# Get X-Forwarded-For Real IP in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, nginx, kibana, logstash-grok

I'm new to Elastic and need help to find the real IP of nginx site visitor.

The environment I have is Nginx module installed in Filebeat and reading the data passed via logstash to elasticsearch and viewed in kibana.

The site I have is proxied via Cloudflare, and as the documentation says here:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/exported-fields-nginx.html

Is that (nginx.access.remote_ip_list) will read the X-Forwarded-For (which is the real ip of visitor and not cloudflare's IP)

But when checking this field in kibana, it gives Cloudflare's IP.

What shall I do to get the Real visitor IP?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question now, but for those that find it, the best answer is going to be using Nginx's '[set_real_ip_from](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html)' and related directives to know when/how to look at headers such as X-Forwarded-For. That way, not only are your logs now correct, but you can also use that in policies and pass it to other backend applications.